# How to change text content in bottomNavigationView dynamically

Tags: android, menu, bottomnavigationview

I've got bottomNavigationView which is already created and attach to activity. Currently I'm trying to find out how to change text in one of navigation items which are inflated from res-menu dynamically.

I've tried to look into existing threads and none of that help me (I've already tried to pick menu from onCreateOptionsMenu and change it with setTitle option later but that wouldn't change text in the activity)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}

//later update on button click (this action is performed)
menu.findItem(R.id.secondItem).setTitle("New Text");
```

I've expected to change text to "New Text" but it's still same as before

Comment: Try this [link](https://tutorialwing.com/android-bottom-navigation-view-tutorial-with-example)

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a while of trying I've finally figured out how to do that. Instead of taking menu during *onCreateOptionsMenu* I've pick menu directly from bottomNavigationView when I click on the button

```
//your code to invoke this action
Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
menu.getItem(2).setTitle("New Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method inside your `activity/fragment`:

```
 public void setNavigationTitle(String title) {
    MenuItem menuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_navigation_next);
    menuItem.setTitle(title);
}
```